# Do synchronized code blocks only block for assignments or for the entire block body?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, java.util.concurrent

I have a data var, `monthArray`, that is read by multiple consumers and periodically updataed by a single periodicall scheduled updater thread. All asynchronously.

I have considered both of these options to perform the update safely.

```
    ArrayList<String> tempArray = ModelJob.getDistinctMonths(user, true);       
    synchronized (monthArray) {
        monthArray = tempArray;
    }
```

or

```
    synchronized (monthArray) {
        monthArray = ModelJob.getDistinctMonths(user, true);
    }
```

The idea behind the first one being that the `ModelJob.getDistinctMonths(user, true);` call is time consuming and I dont want to hold the synchrinzation to block for longer then it has to, only for the quick reassignment of the old array with the updated array. However seems to be a obfuscated, and I only want to do it if completly nessecary. Can anyone give me any insight into how the jvm handles this synchrization and weather or not doing the former will give me any increase in performanace? Basically Im asking if the jvm would block for the whole static ModelJob call, or if it is able to get away with only blocking for the reassignment and be safe, and if so, if it is smart enought to do so.

Comment: An empty block `synchronized(monthArray) { }` will still wait to obtain a lock. The contents of the block are not important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that you don't *need* the synchronization around the `getDistinctMonths()` call (that call is thread-safe, and you don't need atomicity around the call and the assignment), then you can just synchronize around the assignment (and yes, the blocking is only scoped to the synchronized block, otherwise the syntax would be pointless).  Note, @JohnVint brings up a good point that you should not synchronize on the `monthArray` reference as it is being modified.  you must synchronize on a separate object instance which does not change.

Lastly, you could remove the synchronization block and make the `monthArray` member volatile and achieve the same results.

Comment: Even with many updater threads it is equally thread-safe. The second version has in fact exactly the same semantics as `volatile` (assuming `synchronized` reads, of course).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - yes, but with multiple update threads, you could end up losing the "latest" data (depending on which thread updates the reference last).  this is also true about the sync version depending on how you scope the sync block, but i was mainly pointing out that with a single update thread, none of that matters and you can just use volatile.

Comment: You can remove your assumption of one writer thread and your statement will be just as true, if not 'truer' :-)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - yeah, i guess as the statement is currently written, that is true.

Comment: As a general rule, I try to synchronize only on `final` references.

Answer (score 1):

If you just put the `volatile` modifier on the `monthArray` and remove all `synchronized` blocks, you'll have lock-free thread safety.

Also, the JVM may optimize your cleaner (second) version of code to execute as if it was the first version. So, if keeping locks, better stick to the cleaner version.

Answer (score 1):

Using the first approach will be better from performance point of view. It will avoid unnecessary synchronization.

One thing you have to remember is that even the **read** on monthArray will need to be synchronized. Synchronization only works when both update and read are synchronized using the same object lock. I would prefer to use the class Object lock. For example, if this code is a part of class ModelUpdate then use following code

```
synchronized(ModelUpdate.class) {
        monthArray = tempArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A synchronized block will always block for its entire execution. The object (monthArray in your case) given as the parameter is called the "monitor" and will guarantee, that all other synchronized blocks with the same object (monthArray) as parameter will be executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious flaw here is that you should not synchronize on objects that will be changing.

I would prefer the first example but instead use a common lock

```
final Object lock = new Object();

synchronized(lock){
   monthArr = ...;
}
```

However as most said declaring monthArr `volatile` will have the same effects.